# Adjusting height according to dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with dynamically added div's and adjusting parent's height according to dynamically added content.

So, I have a div called `#full-content-wrap` and it's **width** divided with two child elements. These element's are called `.doubled-wrap-content-left` and `.doubled-wrap-content-right` (**let's call it left wrap and right wrap**). So, then, I have a two links (or buttons, or whatever) so when I click on one of these links, javascript add a element `.doubled-table` dynamically to left or right wrap (according which link i clicked). So, but I have a bit problem with setting height of `#full-content-wrap` or left/right wrap.

When I set a full-cont-wrap's height to auto, and l-r wrap's height to auto too, it's still 0px. When I set 100% - auto it's still 100% and added elements are overflowing off the parent element. So I've done it this way. I have created a function that adjusts height of full-cont-wrap to biggest height of it's content (left or right wrap) and when it's empty, to `window.innerHeight`. But, it's kinda uncomfortable and it has two minuses. **The first one** is that when I change size of my browser, then I reload page and maximize window, the height is smaller than innerHeight of maximized window (this happens when I open inspect element function). **The second one** is as you can realise, it's unnecessary JS counting and setting of height.

**Question is:** How to do this simply in CSS without JS?

Things like: Divs are floating etc. I know and I have tried set `display` to every value.

Additional questions comment please :/

```
<div id="full-content-wrap">

<div id="section-name">
    <span>Dashboard</span>
    <span class="section-subname">statistics and more</span>
</div>

<div id="doubled-wrap-content">
    <div id="doubled-wrap-content-left">
        <div class="doubled-table">
            <div class="table-header">
                <div class="caption">
                    <span class="fa fa-cogs"></span>
                    <span class="caption-content">Server Control</span>
                </div>

                <div class="tools">
                    <div class="picon-collapse"></div>
                    <div class="picon-remove"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="doubled-wrap-content-right">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
function setContentWrap () {

/* Set width for full-wrap-content */

var width = screen.width;
width -= 220;

var percent = ((width * 100) / screen.width);

$("#full-content-wrap").css({ width: percent + '%' });


/* Set height for full-wrap-content */

var left = $('#doubled-wrap-content-left')[0].offsetHeight;

var right = $('#doubled-wrap-content-right')[0].offsetHeight;

var sidePanel = $('.side-panel-menu')[0].offsetHeight;

var side = false;
var bigger = 0, b = "";
if (left > right) { bigger = left; b = "left"; }
else if (right > left) { bigger = right; b = "right"; }
else if (right == left) { bigger = right || left; }

if (bigger < sidePanel) {
    bigger = sidePanel;
    side = true;
}

var height = 0, j = 0;
$('#full-content-wrap').each(function () {
    var n = this.children;
    var length = this.children.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        if (n[i].id == 'doubled-wrap-content') break;

        height += n[i].style.height || n[i].offsetHeight;
        j++;
    }
});

var more = 0;
$('#doubled-wrap-content').each(function () {
    if ( more < this.children.length ) {
        more = this.children.length;
    }
});

if (side == false) {
    height += bigger + (more * 60);
} else {
    height = window.innerHeight;
}
$('#full-content-wrap').css({ minHeight: height + 'px' });


var setTo = window.innerHeight;
if (parseInt($('#full-content-wrap').css('minHeight'), 10) <     window.innerHeight) {
    $('#full-content-wrap').css({ height: setTo + 'px' });
    //$('#full-content-wrap').css({ height: '100%' });
}

}
```

Hope it's all. Because those spaces here are ....ooh

Comment: Instead of saying what you have and what you have in it and which one is left and which one is right, provide your code

Comment: if you are displaying tabular data, using a `<table>` tag is best - tables have a bad press and tubs are sometimes thumped by the less experienced, but really they should be used for tabular data, just not for layout

Comment: Anything else ? I am using divs and not table. I asked for help with this. I don't want to use table because of reasons which are secret. :D

Comment: I think it would be much easier to understand the problem if you put the code in jsfiddle so that we could test it immediately.

Comment: I have already figured out how to do this. I have fixed side panel, upper panel and tables are added into one single div. This div only adjust position in page and is a container. Now I add .left .right tables and according to this classname, it's positioned in page. So when I add tables, the body is automatically computed by the it's content and here the overflow comes to show. And when I remove these tables the body's height adjust. It's not so much sorted but who will ever insight in the dynamically generated code in page inspect ? I have realised something about people here. You are just s